# Validation is not working properly while UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, web-config

In my application , i am using clienside validation to validate particular controls which are rendered from partial view.Partial view coding :

```
   <fieldset>
   <div>
      <div>
         <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID) %>
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field"> 
         <%=Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)%>
         <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderID) %>
         <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID) %>
   </div>
   </div>
   <fieldset>
```

After rendering this partial view . i added this with form.

Its not working properly(didnot display error message) when the controls are render in partial view.
Then i render this control in normal view its working fine.

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>  
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true">
```

After i set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is false . then i put my control in partial . now its working. but it is not proper way.i want to do it in proper way .

Any idea about this.

sorry i forgot one thing when i was using html begin form in inside partial view with UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled= true . that time also it working.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah. You need to give 110%!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your field is inside a form because validation messages don't render if the field is not inside a form.

If it is not the reason, show us the validation attribute you're using for this field.

**Edit**: Maybe obvious, but check that the unobstrusive .js scripts are being loaded. Put the link right in the place that the fields are being validated to confirm it.

**Edit 2**: Look at the generated html code. Check if the validation messages are beging generated or not. The Rick Anderson idea also seems to be a good starting point in order to find the problem.

Comment: Hi jonathan , thanks for your update i check field is in inside the form.

>        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Order ID is required.")]
        public int OrderID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: i checked that script is perfectly loaded. is any other suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Do a view source for the working version and the non-working version and compare. That will show you what you are doing wrong. A partial view should be no different than a view that contains the partial markup.